# Missing devise routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

```
Rails 5.1
Devise
```

My routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions',
      confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
      passwords: 'users/passwords',
      registrations: 'users/registrations',
      unlocks: 'users/unlocks',
      invitations: 'users/invitations'
  }

  root to: "landings#index"
  resources :users
  resources :followeds
  resources :followers
  resources :locations
  resources :fw_exports

  get 'import_spreadsheet', to: :upload_spreadsheet, controller: 'fw_exports'
  post 'parse_imported_spreadsheet_and_confirm', to: :process_imported_spreadsheet_and_confirm, controller: 'fw_exports'
  post 'process_parsed_spreadsheet', to: :process_parsed_spreadsheet, controller: 'fw_exports'

  scope module: :landings do
    get 'visitors'
  end

end
```

When I generate routes, here's what I get:

```
                            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
                  new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                          users/sessions#new
                      user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                          users/sessions#create
              destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                         users/sessions#destroy
                 new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                     users/passwords#new
                edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                    users/passwords#edit
                     user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                         users/passwords#update
                                   PUT    /users/password(.:format)                         users/passwords#update
                                   POST   /users/password(.:format)                         users/passwords#create
          cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                           users/registrations#cancel
             new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                          users/registrations#new
            edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                             users/registrations#edit
                 user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                  users/registrations#update
                                   PUT    /users(.:format)                                  users/registrations#update
                                   DELETE /users(.:format)                                  users/registrations#destroy
                                   POST   /users(.:format)                                  users/registrations#create
            accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)                users/invitations#edit
            remove_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/remove(.:format)                users/invitations#destroy
               new_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)                   users/invitations#new
                   user_invitation PATCH  /users/invitation(.:format)                       users/invitations#update
                                   PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)                       users/invitations#update
                                   POST   /users/invitation(.:format)                       users/invitations#create
                              root GET    /                                                 landings#index
                             users GET    /users(.:format)                                  users#index
                                   POST   /users(.:format)                                  users#create
                          new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                              users#new
                         edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                         users#edit
                              user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                              users#show
                                   PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                              users#update
                                   PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                              users#update
                                   DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                              users#destroy
                         followeds GET    /followeds(.:format)                              followeds#index
                                   POST   /followeds(.:format)                              followeds#create
                      new_followed GET    /followeds/new(.:format)                          followeds#new
                     edit_followed GET    /followeds/:id/edit(.:format)                     followeds#edit
                          followed GET    /followeds/:id(.:format)                          followeds#show
                                   PATCH  /followeds/:id(.:format)                          followeds#update
                                   PUT    /followeds/:id(.:format)                          followeds#update
                                   DELETE /followeds/:id(.:format)                          followeds#destroy
                         followers GET    /followers(.:format)                              followers#index
                                   POST   /followers(.:format)                              followers#create
                      new_follower GET    /followers/new(.:format)                          followers#new
                     edit_follower GET    /followers/:id/edit(.:format)                     followers#edit
                          follower GET    /followers/:id(.:format)                          followers#show
                                   PATCH  /followers/:id(.:format)                          followers#update
                                   PUT    /followers/:id(.:format)                          followers#update
                                   DELETE /followers/:id(.:format)                          followers#destroy
                         locations GET    /locations(.:format)                              locations#index
                                   POST   /locations(.:format)                              locations#create
                      new_location GET    /locations/new(.:format)                          locations#new
                     edit_location GET    /locations/:id/edit(.:format)                     locations#edit
                          location GET    /locations/:id(.:format)                          locations#show
                                   PATCH  /locations/:id(.:format)                          locations#update
                                   PUT    /locations/:id(.:format)                          locations#update
                                   DELETE /locations/:id(.:format)                          locations#destroy
                        fw_exports GET    /fw_exports(.:format)                             fw_exports#index
                                   POST   /fw_exports(.:format)                             fw_exports#create
                     new_fw_export GET    /fw_exports/new(.:format)                         fw_exports#new
                    edit_fw_export GET    /fw_exports/:id/edit(.:format)                    fw_exports#edit
                         fw_export GET    /fw_exports/:id(.:format)                         fw_exports#show
                                   PATCH  /fw_exports/:id(.:format)                         fw_exports#update
                                   PUT    /fw_exports/:id(.:format)                         fw_exports#update
                                   DELETE /fw_exports/:id(.:format)                         fw_exports#destroy
                import_spreadsheet GET    /import_spreadsheet(.:format)                     fw_exports#import_spreadsheet
parse_imported_spreadsheet_and_confirm POST   /parse_imported_spreadsheet_and_confirm(.:format) fw_exports#parse_imported_spreadsheet_and_confirm
        process_parsed_spreadsheet POST   /process_parsed_spreadsheet(.:format)             fw_exports#process_parsed_spreadsheet
                          visitors GET    /visitors(.:format)                               landings#visitors
```

Am I not supposed to also be getting routes for confirmatins and unlocks?

Comment: I have nearly the exact same configuration as you, and I'm getting the same behavior when I run rake routes, but the routes are in-fact working.

Comment: Have you followed the rest of the steps here?: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

Comment: I did not un-comment the :cofirmable, :lockable in user.rb, I did and now I can see the routes

Comment: you don't necessarily need a route ( which is like a public entrance to your controllers). You can call a controller action from another controller, from the inside. I have not checked my routes but they probably look the same as yours.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have commented the **lockable** & **confirmable**. You need to uncomment it inorder to make it work.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  #   :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable
end
```